# An extension is Galois iff it is normal & separable

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm reading some notes on Galois theory and their style seems a little non-standard to me (at least, in comparison to other sources I've seen), so I wanted to check whether my proof (based on what I've learned) is correct.

The basic definitions should be the same as everywhere: an algebraic extension $L/K$ is :

- Galois if $\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Aut}(L/K))=K$,
- normal if every minimal polynomial splits, and
- separable if no minimal polynomial has multiple roots.

I intend to prove that

> $L/K$ is Galois iff it is normal and separable.

The two results from the notes I use are

1. If $K\subset L\subset\overline{L}$, with $\overline{L}$ an algebraic closure of $L$ and $L/K$ normal, then every $K$-homomorphism $\varphi:L\to\overline{L}$ is a $K$-automorphism of $L$.
2. If $K,K'$ are isomorphic and $L,L'$ are algebraic closures of the two, then there is an isomorphism of $L$ and $L'$ extending the isomorphism of $K$ and $K'$. A corollary of this is that if $K$ is embedded in an algebraically closed field, the embedding can be extended to $L$.

Now with the proof (the first part is standard, the second part is what I wonder about):

> Suppose $L/K$ is Galois and $\alpha\in L$, let $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ be the distinct images of $\alpha$ under $\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$. We show the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $g(x)=\prod_i(x-\alpha_i)$, from which follows the normality and separability of $L/K$. Firstly, $g$ is mapped to itself by applying $\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$ to the coefficients, so $g\in\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Aut}(L/K))[x]=K[x]$. Let $f\in K[x]$ be some polynomial with $\alpha$ as root, then obviously all the $\alpha_i$ are roots of $f$ as well, so $g|f$. In particular $g$ divides the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, which in turn divides $g$, so they're equal.

> Now suppose $L/K$ is normal and separable, we want to show that for every $\alpha\in L\setminus K$ exists a $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(L/K)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)\neq\alpha$. If instead of $L$ we consider its image in $\overline{K}$ under a $K$-embedding and show the existence of such a map in that situation, we can transport this map back to $L$ and get the desired $\sigma$, so let $K\subset L\subset\overline{L}$. By our assumptions there is a $\beta\in L$, a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ such that $\beta\neq\alpha$. Let $F:=K(\alpha),F':=K(\beta)$, there is a $K$-isomorphism $\varphi:F\to F'$ and since $\overline{K}$ is an algebraic closure of both there exists an automorphism $\overline{\sigma}:\overline{K}\to\overline{K}$ extending $\varphi$, which implies $\overline{\sigma}\in\operatorname{Aut}(\overline{K}/K)$ and $\overline{\sigma}(\alpha)=\beta$. The restriction $\sigma$ of $\overline{\sigma}$ to $L$ is an automorphism of $L$ by normality of $L/K$, so we are done.

Comment: It seems ok to me.